# Prefix not appeared n on generated XML

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I've this XSD Schema definition

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx">
    <xs:element name="myRootElemnt">
       <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="messageType">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:short" name="id" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="time" />
                <xs:element type="xs:short" name="date" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The generated XML is:

[image]

But, the XML still incomplete, it must contains `xmlns:ns2="http://www.xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx">` and the prefix ns2 for the root element , like this:

[image]

Any Solutions?

Comment: With the Result you're showing, you have elements from two different namespaces: <ns2:myRootElemnt> in namespace `http://www.xxx.xxxxx`, and all the others, in no namespace. That means you need at least two XSD files, one for each namespace, and one must import the other. Remember that the one with namespace must indicate the target namespace.

Comment: hello @kumesana , thanks for your response, i think its like this, but i have not the xsd referenced by ns2, is there any solution to just modify the generated xml to contains the prefixes ? i use package-info and i could add xmlns:ns2="http://www.xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx , but still not get prefix for myRootElemnt

Comment: "but i have not the xsd referenced by ns2" well make one -\_-°. Or you could forget about XSD and use JAXB annotations if you prefer.